# Subversion web interface

Tags: linux, svn, centos, plesk

I have recently installed Subversion onto a Linux server ([CentOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS)) and everything works great.

I am wondering if there are any web interfaces available for managing the repositories i.e. create / delete repositories, manage users and permissions, view revision history, etc.

The idea is that I can do everything via a web interface instead of using SSH.

Incidentally I have [Plesk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plesk)/virtuozzo on this server (and Webmin on another test server) so if there is something that can integrate directly to these then even better!

Comment: VisualSVN Server has a modern web UI for SVN repositories. It supports Markdown, viewing MS Work docx files, has repo search capabilities and a lot of other useful features. Try it on the demo server at https://demo-server.visualsvn.com/!/#

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Subversion people have a [links list](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/branches/python-3-compatibility/www/links.html) which references a ton of material related to Subversion including management and different web interfaces.

I haven't used it, but [Submin](http://supermind.nl/submin/index.html) might be what you're looking for.

If you're looking for simple repository browsing mod_dav_svn is minimal and works.

[Trac](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trac) was already suggested, but that has more bug-tracking-wiki-project-management features, but very little administration of SVN out of the box.

Comment: The URL for http://subversion.tigris.org/links.html is now a 404. Does anyone have an updated URL? I have not yet found a similar page at http://subversion.apache.org yet.

Comment: Finally here it is: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/branches/python-3-compatibility/www/links.html

Answer (score 9):

Take also a look at:
http://www.usvn.info/

Comment: this one is really great

Answer (score 4):

This may be a repeat of what others have said, but I've looked at many options. The best may be these:

- [submin](http://supermind.nl/submin/about.html) (Linux)
- [VisualSVN](http://demo-server.visualsvn.com/!/) (Windows)
- [RVskin](http://www.rvskin.com/) (for Linux/[cPanel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPanel))

*[Creating your own custom Subversion management layer](http://www.troyhunt.com/2009/10/creating-your-own-custom-subversion.html)* inspired me to check into VisualSVN, but I have not tested it though.

Comment: VisualSVN doesn't appear to offer a web interface.

Comment: @reinerpost VisualSVN Server offers web **user** interface only. Take a look at demo here: http://demo-server.visualsvn.com/

Answer (score 2):

[Trac](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trac) may serve your purposes, but I'm not sure how much control over the actual day-to-day SVN commands it gives you. It does have a very nice interface for viewing SVN revisions however. Have a [look here](http://trac.openstreetmap.org/browser/applications/rendering/gosmore) for an example of a [Trac](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trac) page for gosmore, and [OpenStreetMap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenStreetMap) routing program to get an idea of what it is like.

There is also [websvn](http://websvn.tigris.org/) and [viewsvn](http://viewsvn.berlios.de/), but I can't seem to find any that actually allow you to upload files to check in or anything like that. They are all aimed at viewing the repository, downloading files, viewing logs and comparing revisions.

In terms of the day-to-day check-in, check-out stuff, you are probably better off using the `svn` command or a friendly GUI like [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) (if using from Windows) for that sort of thing.

Comment: Nope. Trac does not allow you to manage svn users and repositories.

Answer (score 1):

SVN professionals suggest [Subversion Edge](http://www.collab.net/products/subversion).

> ```
> Install and Update: Certified binaries, wizard driven installers with 1-click updates
> Repository Management: Create, manage, browse, and local backup
> User Management: Manage roles, permissions and access rules
> Administration: Authentication, server management and health analytics
> Desktops & IDEs: Eclipse, Visual Studio, AnkhSVN, Subclipse, and more
> Cloud Services: Public cloud backup and restore to CollabNet CloudForge
> TeamForge: Adds multi-server Subversion replication, code governance, improved network performance, as well as Agile ALM through DevOps
> Git: Upgrade to TeamForge from SubversionEdge to manage your Git and SVN repositories within one environment
> ```

I'm really excited about it and am currently setting it up (it is Java application, so it takes some time to set it up properly compared to an ordinary web UI).

Answer (score -2):

You may want to checkout [VoilàSVN](http://www.voilasvn.com/) or [OpenGrok](http://opengrok.github.io/OpenGrok/)

Comment: Maybe, but they are not web-based Subversion administration interfaces.