# Web Based SVN Solution hosting on Server

Tags: svn, hosting

I am in a requirement to setup a web bases SVN server.

Like any other Subversion, I wanted to make it on my live server for may private use only.

Can you please suggest any web based SVN, So that I can install and test ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on Windows, the quickest and best path is [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/)

Comment: Hello Stuart Lange, You you are perfectly right , but what If I want to host web server on shared hosting ? support I purchased the hosting from some party and I want to host there. Than ?

Comment: Great, Thanks Stuart Lange. Do you have any idea like I wanted to host the SVN on my server like PHP based web SVN so I can host on my server and add as many file/user as I want and does not dependent on third party server. As an example like Mantis Bug Tracking is open source where host that on my server. I hope you get the requirement.

Comment: Do you think that, This question is valid ? as some one given -1 Rank ? Can you please provide me your feedback on the same and do needful if you can ?

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding exactly what you want.  If you want to install and run your own svn server on your own physical servers, look at the SVN book (http://svnbook.red-bean.com/), specifically the bit on installation (http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.intro.install.html).  Subversion is inherently "web based" (it runs on the Apache web server).  If you are looking for a web *interface* to browse your svn repositories, check out this SO question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/565628).